# Lightning Component Error For Case Close Button

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

Trying to create a Lightning button to close a case and I am getting this error

> Uncaught Unable to find action 'getCaseStatusPickList' on the controller of c:Button Callback failed: apex://closeCaseApex/ACTION$getCase

After adding in the getCaseStatusPickList method I am getting another error:

> Uncaught Assertion Failed!: run() cannot be called on a server action. Use $A.enqueueAction() instead. : false

Below is the updated code

Button.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="closeCaseApex" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Case"/>
<aura:attribute name="caseStatus" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="caseId" type="String" default="{!v.recordId}"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral newsbutton" style="float:right"  onclick="{!c.closeCases}">Close Case</button>
```

closeCaseApex.apxc

```
public class closeCaseApex{
@AuraEnabled
public static Case getCase(Id caseId){
    return ([Select Id, Status From Case Where id=:caseId]);
}
@AuraEnabled
public static Case closeCases(Case caseA){
   update caseA;
   return caseA;
}
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Case> getCaseStatusPickList(String caseId){
   return([Select Status From Case]);
}}
```

ButtonHelper.js

```
({
getStatusPickListValue : function(component) {

    var action = component.get("c.getCaseStatusPickList");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        var hasImg = false;
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {

            var statusPickList = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.lstCaseStatus", statusPickList);

            console.log('status picklist ::', component.get("v.lstCaseStatus"));
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

},})
```

ButtonController.js

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
component.set("v.isError", false)
component.set("v.showEditView", false);
component.set("v.errorMsg", "");

var action = component.get("c.getCase");
action.setParams({
    caseId : component.get("v.caseId")
});

action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.record", a.getReturnValue());
        helper.getStatusPickListValue(component);
    }
});

$A.enqueueAction(action);
},

closeCase : function (component, event, helper) {
var action = component.get("c.closeCases");
var Status = component.get("v.record.Status") //get value of field
//console.log("Status: " Status);
//action.setParams({Status : Closed});
var caseId = component.get("v.record").Id;
action.setParams({caseA: {Id: caseId, Status : "Closed"}});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
},
})
```

Comment: where is the backend method getCaseStatusPickList ?

Comment: I need another method in my apex class for example public static Case getCaseStatus(){} which queries for the status of the case.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a method called "getCaseStatusPickList" in your Apex Class. I recommend you to check your function names at ButtonController.js because you wrote "closeCase" but you are calling for "closeCases" at Button.cmp